# Insert list into mysql using python - Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql, list

I'm trying to insert a list into multiple columns in a mysql database.
But I keep getting this error: "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement"

I'm new to this, but as I understand it, I'm supposed to use question marks in the statement to avoid SQL Injections.

This is the script:

```
import mysql.connector

wlcdb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="fqdn-server",
user="db-user",
password="sure",
database="cisco_wlc")

sqlcursor = wlcdb.cursor()

liste = ['3HETF3WP', 'DHP4QB6B', 'TQDAEPRY', 'Q7GFC2A6', 'DVXD3PXX']

params = ['?' for item in liste]
print (params)
sql = 'INSERT INTO wlc_mpsk (field0, field1, field2, field3, field4) VALUES (%s);' % ','.join(params)
print (sql)
sqlcursor.execute(sql, liste)
```

And when executing, the error comes:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: You only passed 1 parameter when the query expects 5. It doesn't matter what that single parameter contains, it's still a single parameter

Comment: Thanks for answering.
How do I change the script so it passes 5 parameters then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will work:

```py
sqlcursor = wlcdb.cursor()

liste = ['3HETF3WP', 'DHP4QB6B', 'TQDAEPRY', 'Q7GFC2A6', 'DVXD3PXX']

sql = 'INSERT INTO wlc_mpsk (field0, field1, field2, field3, field4) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
sqlcursor.execute(sql, liste)

wlcdb.commit()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
liste = ['3HETF3WP', 'DHP4QB6B', 'TQDAEPRY', 'Q7GFC2A6', 'DVXD3PXX']
sql = "INSERT INTO wlc_mpsk (field0, field1, field2, field3, field4) VALUES (%s);"  % ("'"+"','".join(liste)+"'")
print(sql)
```

It's easier if you write this

Comment: What you wrote allows SQL injection attacks and conversion bugs. Imagine if one of the strings was `'); drop table users; -- `. Or a date. You'd end up with localized strings that may or may not be parsed correctly by the database server